# Loop a mysql result array auto into JSON array or XML key duplication

Tags: php, arrays

I am returning a mysql array from a result and wanting to automatically output the result into part of a JSON return or XML (other stuff besides this is included) and wanted to use a simple loop function for output. It works great except the duplication of array index/key. For example:

```
[23] => 21.00
[cost] => 21.00
[24] => 0.00
[costproduct] => 0.00
[25] => 21.00
[costtotal] => 21.00
```

I would like it to be clean without the duplication. The simple piece of code I was using to loop was:

```
function array_loop_output( $array, $format = 'json', $output = '' ){

    if(is_array($array)){

        foreach($array as $key => $value){

            if(is_array($value)){

                if($format == 'xml'){

                    $output .= '<' . $key . '>';

                    $output .= array_loop_output( $value, $format );

                    $output .= '</' . $key . '>';

                }else{

                    $output[$key] = array_loop_output( $value, $format );

                }

            }else{

                if($format == 'xml'){

                    if(is_numeric($value)){

                        $output .= xmltagstring(array('tag'=>$key,'value'=>$value))."\n";

                    }else{

                        $output .= xmltagstring(array('tag'=>$key,'value'=>$value,'cdata'=>true))."\n";

                    }

                }else{ // json

                    if(is_numeric($value)){

                        $output[$key] = $value;

                    }else{

                        $output[$key] = forjson($value);

                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;

}
```

Is there a clean way to do this as I think im having one of my blond moments? Many thanks.

Comment: Where are the numerical keys coming from? Looks like you're using `mysql_fetch_array()` or `mysqli_result::fetch_array()`. Instead you should fetch `assoc` not `array`.

Comment: Thats exactly what im doing. Knew I was doing something silly. Thanks for pointing that out to me feel like an idiot now and yes it works now.

Comment: Is this solved now then?

Comment: Yeah I would like to give you the answer credit

Comment: Added as an answer with more details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of result that has both numerical keys and associative keys is due to the use of one of the fetch array functions:

- `mysqli_result::fetch_array()`
- `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`
- `mysql_fetch_array()`

If you use `assoc` instead of `array`, the result will only contain the [string] associative keys:

- `mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()`
- `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`
- `mysql_fetch_assoc()`